# Apply a patch only if it doesn't break anything

Tags: linux, bash, patch

I'm trying to apply a multitude of patches only if dry-run option doesn't return an error.

But for the moment I can only try or apply all the patches:

`for i in /home/me/patch/*.patch; do patch -Np1 -f --dry-run < $i; done`

Thus patches that generate a "hunk FAILED" should not be applied.

If anyone has an idea. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following ***grep*** approach:

```
for i in /home/me/patch/*.patch; do 
    if ! grep -q 'hunk FAILED' <(patch -Np1 -f --dry-run < $i); then
        patch -Np1 -f < $i
    fi
done
```

---

Or verifying `patch` exit status (with `-s`(`--silent`) option):

```
for i in /home/me/patch/*.patch; do 
    if patch -Np1 -f -s --dry-run < $i; then
        patch -Np1 -f < $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: why not just `if grep`, no need for `[[]]` or `$()`

Comment: @123, in that case we should add `-q` option, see my update

Comment: Clever but I tested it applies only patches where result "hunk FAILED" is found.

Comment: @r516086 Yep should be `if ! grep`

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thanks !

Comment: Do you even need `grep`? The exit status of `patch` alone should be enough to determine if the patch succeeded or not.